# how to print a matrix on c++ using ncurses?

Tags: c++, matrix, ncurses

I'm learning a few things about ncurses on c++ and my problem is that I want to print a matrix of strings on the screen of ncurses but some functions like printw(), addstr(), didnt let to add a thing like this....

```
string matrix[10][10];
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < 10; j++){
        printw("%s", matrix[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`matrix[i][j]` evaluates to a `std::string`. You cannot use a `std::string` as a valid argument to `printw`.

Instead of

```
    printw("%s", matrix[i][j]);
```

use

```
    printw("%s", matrix[i][j].c_str());
```